# How iterate with a certain value?

Tags: matlab

I am a newbie in Matlab. I want to find a way like in python to iterate over certain values.

In python it would like it something like that:

```
for i in [0, 90, 180, 360]:
    print('degree', i)
```

But, how to do this in Matlab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short version:**

Do this:

```
myvar = [0, 90, 180, 360];
for i = 1:size(myvar, 2)
    ival = myvar(:, i);
    disp(['degree', num2str(ival)]);
end
```

**Long version:**

MATLAB doesn't have anything equivalent to Python iterators.  Its loop rules are fundamentally different.

Your code will actually work MATLAB roughly as written in python:

```
for i = [0, 90, 180, 360]
    disp(['degree', num2str(i)]);
end
```

**However**, that is because this is a special case in MATLAB that, by coincidence, happens to have a similar result to the one in Python.  But MATLAB is doing something very different, so seemingly similar code that would work in Python will silently do a completely different thing in MATLAB.

Python's loop rules depend on the iterator protocol, which iterable classes like lists and numpy arrays follow.  Generally, it loops over the "outer" sequence.  In nested lists, it is the outermost list.  In numpy arrays, it is the last dimension.

MATLAB's loop rules are as follow: it flattens the matrix into a 2D matrix if it has more than two dimension, then loops over the second dimension.  In other words, the `n`th time through the loop gives you the `n`th *column* of your loop variable, after the loop variable has been flattened into a 2D matrix.  So in your case, you have a 2D matrix where the first dimension is `1` and the second dimension is `4`.  So it loops over the second dimension, giving you 4 `1x1` matrices (there is no such thing as 1D or 0D data types in MATLAB like there are in Python).

However, if you had a column vector, like this:

```
for i = [0; 90; 180; 360]
    disp(['degree', num2str(i)]);
end
```

You would get an error:

```
Error using horzcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent
```

... because instead of getting 4 `1x1` matrices you would get 1 `4x1` matrix, because the original matrix is a `4x1` matrix and so has a second dimension of `1`.  If you start with a `4x5` matrix, you would get 5 `4x1` matrices.  If you start with a `4x5x6` matrices, you would get 30 (`5*6`) `4x1` matrices.

Also, it always returns the same data type you got in.  So if you start with a `1x4` cell array, you will get `1x1` cell arrays out, rather than whatever is in the cell array.  So there isn't much point using cell arrays directly, either.

Overall, what this means is that using a variable directly in a loop, like this:

```
for i = myvar
   % do something
end
```

...is extremely dangerous in MATLAB.  This only works reliably if you can be absolutely 100% sure `myvar` is always a row vector.  But if you try to expand the code, or use it in a new situation, it can silently do the wrong thing.  And do to other MATLAB internal features and functions that also silently do the wrong thing, it is easy for this sort of code to seem to work fine will giving you a completely wrong result.

So you rarely see this sort of approach in MATLAB, what people usually do is use an index variable.  They create a sequence of indices in the loop and loop over those.  A common approach is this

```
myvar = [0, 90, 180, 360];
for i = 1:length(myvar)
    ivar = myvar(i);
end
```

So in this case `i` is the index of `myvar` you want to use.  This approach, although common, is also dangerous.  Unlike `numpy` where `len` always gives a consistent dimension (the first one), `length` in MATLAB gives you the *longest* dimension, whatever that might be.  So it acts unpredictably if given 2D matrices.  And because MATLAB treats single indices as indices of a flattened version of the matrix, it will again silently do the wrong thing.

So the only safe way of doing this is to manually specify the dimension you want using the `size` function, or if you want to loop over all values in a multidimensional array use the `numel` function to get the total number of elements:

```
for i=1:size(myvar, 2)
   ivar = myvar(:, i);
end

for i=1:numel(myvar)
   ivar = myvar(i);
end
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for i = [0, 90, 180, 360]
    fprintf('degree %d\n', i)
end
```

shows:

```
degree 0
degree 90
degree 180
degree 360
```

Comment: That will only work in the OPs specific example, but it won't work for the general case of iterating over values which is what the question asks.  In python the OPs example isn't a special case, but in MATLAB it is.